# Bandwidth Sharing Game example

Tags: game-theory

This example is from Narahari's textbook on Game theory.

I am not sure I understand the last part: the set of $n$ simultaneous equations has the unique solution: $$x_i^*=1/(1+n).$$

Basically, I don't see how that follows and how we actually derive the solution.

In reverse, the above means that $\sum_{j\neq i}x_j=\frac{n-1}{n+1}$ which again doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

I'd appreciate any help. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a direct approach that avoids using vectors and matrices.

The best reply condition for agent $i$ is
$$x_i = \frac{1-\sum_{j\ne i} x_j}{2} \qquad i = 1\, \ldots, n$$
Rewrite this as
$$(*) \qquad x_i + \sum_{j=1}^n x_j = 1 \qquad i = 1\, \ldots, n$$
Please note that the sum extends over $j=1, \ldots, n$.

Add up the $n$ equations for $i = 1\, \ldots, n$ to get
$$\sum_{j=1}^n x_j + n \left( \sum_{j=1}^n x_j \right) = n$$
Collecting, you find
$$\sum_{j=1}^n x_j = \frac{n}{n+1}$$
Replace this in (*) to find
$$x_i + \frac{n}{n+1} = 1$$
and the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

We want to solve $$2x_i^* + \sum_{j \ne i}x_j^* = 1$$

This can be written as a matrix system:

$$(ee^T+I)x=e$$

where $e$ is the all one vector.

By [matrix determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma), we have

$$\det(ee^T+I)=(1+e^Te)\det(I)=n+1\ne0$$ Hence the solution is unique.

Let's verify that $x=\frac{e}{n+1}$ is the solution.

$$(ee^T+I)\frac{e}{n+1}=\frac{1}{n+1}(e(e^Te)+e)=\frac{1}{n+1}(en+e)=e$$

Hence, it is the solution.